# How to write SQL with python without an ORM?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I am connecting to a PostgreSQL database with python using os.Popen(cmd).
How can I an write the SQL statement without using an ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `psql` to issue your statements to the database via the pipe.

```
sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname from users"
cmd = "psql -c '" + sql + ";' -d dbname -U user"  

result = os.popen(cmd, 'r', 1)
print(result)
```

You need to know the database schema (tables, columns, etc) ahead of time to do this. You also need to be careful about SQL injection.

Comment: Alas, I'm not a PostgreSQL expert. I'm going to assume you can append multiple SQL commands in a single string, separated by semi-colon. You said you're using python 2.7 so `subprocess.run` is not an option.

Comment: In the end what I did is use psql -c "\i  /path/to/sql/file;" -U username -d db_name -pXXXX and it works fine. I create one sql file that contains all my statements.

Comment: If you could accept the answer, that'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: Initially I downvoted you for using `os.popen()` but it turns out that was what the question was asking. In reality the answer here should be not to use `os.popen()` but rather to use one of the many libraries available (e.g., psycopg2).